# Netgem n5200 (or other) - How to get into linux operating system layer?

Tags: linux, shell

After logging by PuTTY to Netgem n5200 device I have open in terminal kind of shell with about 40 commends, but no information about way how to close it and work directly on Linux.

Device has for 99% installed HardHat Linux distribution (MontaVista Linux).
From level of mentioned shell I can use some simple linux command like "! pwd", "! ls -l", "! ps". 
Maybe it would be useful that I'm in tmp dir and I can not leave it at this moment.

I've already study Netgem SDK looking for information and I found nothing, the same result after searching in google, so that's why I came looking for help here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'get into Linux operating system layer'? Or by 'close it and work directly on Linux'?

Comment: What I mean is how can I close mentioned before shell and have possibility to work fully with Linux, so I could use all available commends of this Linux (HardHat), move between directories, open/edit files, embed my own software on device, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try to start the shell using

```
!sh
```

or

```
!bash
```

command.

If not, could you please provide the list of available commands (such as `pwd`, `ls`), may be some of them could be used to get a shell (e.g. `vi`).